# Show that $f(z)=\sum_{n= 0}^{+\infty}a_n z^n$ is a polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, proof-verification

> Let $f(z)=\sum_{n= 0}^{+\infty}a_n z^n$, the radius of convergence $\ge 1$.
>
> For all $n,\quad a_n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is bounded the open unit disk.
>
> Show that $f$ is a polynomial.

My attempt:

for  $0< r< R=1$ we have $a_{n}=\frac{1}{2\pi r^{n}}\int_{0}^{2\pi }f(re^{i\theta })e^{-in\theta }d\theta$ : Cauchy formula.

Then 
$$
 \left | a_{n} \right |\leq \frac{max_{D}\left | f \right |}{r^{n}}
$$

Then I take the limit as $x \rightarrow 1$, is it correct ?

Thanks

Sorry I deleted : I think it's incorrect.

Comment: You want to show that it is a polynomial, so you want to show that after a while all the $a_n$ become zero. Suppose that doesnt happen. Recall, if $t_n$ is a sequence whose limit is not zero, what can you say about $\sum t_n$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Parseval's Theorem, you have
$$\int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2\,d\theta = 2\pi(|a_0|^2 + \sum_{n > 0} r^{2n}|a_n|^2) \tag 1$$
(Essentially what is going on here is you are expanding the square, noting that cross terms integrate to zero, then integrating the remaining square terms.)

If infinitely many $a_n$ were nonzero, since they are all integers, taking the limit on the right in $(1)$ gives
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 1} \int_0^{2\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})|^2\,d\theta = \infty$$
This would not occur if $f(z)$ were bounded inside the unit disk. So only finitely many $a_n$ can be nonzero in this situation; that is, $f(z)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: You are just showing the $a_n$ are bounded.. but they still could all be nonzero, such as if each $a_n = 1$. So further argument is needed.